# Why does System.Timeout in Haskell not work for sockets?

Tags: sockets, haskell, networking, timeout

I'm trying to listen for UDP Datagrams for just 3 seconds in Haskell. I wrote some code but I'm not sure why it's not working. I set the timeout to 3 seconds, but it just waits forever and doesn't block

```
import Control.Concurrent  as CC  (forkIO, threadDelay, killThread)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Network.Socket 
import Network.Socket.ByteString as B
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad            (forever)
import System.Timeout

receiveDatagram = do 
  ack <- newIORef (0 :: Int) 
  addrinfos <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just "127.0.0.1") (Just "7001")
  let serveraddr = head addrinfos
  sock <- socket (addrFamily serveraddr) Datagram defaultProtocol
  bind sock (addrAddress serveraddr)
  print "starting"
  tmp <- timeout 3000000 (do
    (msg, addr) <- B.recvFrom sock 1024
    close sock
    writeIORef ack 1
    print msg
    )
  case tmp of 
    Nothing -> close sock
    _       -> print "something else"
  print "timeout done"
```

The documentation for `timeout` states:

> Standard I/O functions like hGetBuf, hPutBuf, Network.Socket.accept, or hWaitForInput appear to be blocking, but they really don't because the runtime system uses scheduling mechanisms like select(2) to perform asynchronous I/O, so it is possible to interrupt standard socket I/O or file I/O using this combinator.

Comment: Personally, I don't like the idea underlying `timeout`, or its use in the code above. What if `recvFrom` succeeds, and just after that the timeout expires, say before `close` (or even before `writeIORef`)? We consume the message from the OS buffer, but `tmp` will report `Nothing`, losing the message (and `ack` might still be zero).

Comment: It works fine for me.  How are you compiling it? What platform? What version of GHC?  EDIT: I used GHC 8.4.4 on OS-X.   EDIT2:  GHC 8.2.0 on Linux also worked fine.

Comment: It might make a difference whether the threaded runtime is used or not, but I gave up trying to trace recvFrom's implementation at a certain point

Comment: I'm using GHCi, version 8.4.4 with stack as building tool under Windows 10.

Comment: @chi I initially had the close statement under the timeout, but I changed the code 1000 times because I thought I wasn't closing the socket at the right time

Comment: And the stack version:
Version 1.7.1, Git revision 681c800873816c022739ca7ed14755e85a579565 (5807 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.28.2

Comment: I'm guessing this is a Windows + GHCi problem, which I can't test.  Try compiling it instead of interpreting it (so, `ghc file.hs -o file` instead of `ghci file.hs`).  If that works then you have a way to continue development. Either way I suggest you file an issue on ghchq.